# React Native: How do I move the text "hello" to the right side of my app instead of in the middle?

Tags: css, react-native

I want to move the text `Hello` to the right side using CSS but I am unable to do so.

It was fine before. But when I added in a library called `react-native-popup-menu` which is importing Menu,
    MenuOptions,
    MenuOption,
    MenuTrigger,
    MenuProvider. When I put Text 'Hello' it the text will be in the middle instead

```
export default class Cluster1 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        search: false,
        dataToShow: []
    }
}
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ dataToShow: ClusterData })
}
searchUpdated = (term) => {
    let matchedItemsArray = []
    if (term === '') {
        this.setState({ search: false, dataToShow: ClusterData })
    } else {
        this.setState({ search: true, dataToShow: ClusterData }, function () {
            ClusterData.map((item) => {
                item.data.map(item1 => {
                    if (item1.name == term) {
                        matchedItemsArray.push(item)
                    }
                })
            })
            this.setState({ dataToShow: matchedItemsArray })
        })
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.top}>
                <TextInput style={styles.search}
                    onChangeText={(term) => { this.searchUpdated(term) }}
                    style={styles.searchInput}
                    placeholder="Type a mood to search" />
                <MenuProvider >
                    <Menu onBackdropPress={() => this.onBackdropPress()}
                    >
                        <MenuTrigger >
                            <Text style={styles.user}>
                                hello
                            </Text>
                        </MenuTrigger>

                        <MenuOptions style={styles.top}>
                            <MenuOption style={styles.top}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.signOut()}>
                                <Text>SignOut</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </MenuOption>
                        </MenuOptions>
                    </Menu>
                </MenuProvider>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
user: {
    paddingRight: 5,
    color: "#841584",

},
top: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomWidth: 4,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
    textAlign: 'center',
},});
```

The Text 'Hello' should be on the right side instead of in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give

> **textAlign : 'right'**

to user style.

```
user: {
    paddingRight: 5,
    color: "#841584",
    textAlign:'right'
}
```